# Click ImageView on Specific Location

Tags: android

I have an imageView and when I need to let the user click only on a specific location (the white space) as shown in the image below, any suggestion?

[image]

here is my **xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lockRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the code

```
    private View.OnTouchListener imageViewOnClickListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
               //here i want if he clicked on specific location to go to another activity
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewerActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
```

I don't know if i should use onClick or onTouchClick!!

Comment: What you want exaclty? What you have worked on it?

Comment: show your xml layout

Comment: So what you need is to click the image, or just an specific little part of it?

Comment: yes just a little part of it as shown in the image above, the white area only @NachoRamosSánchez

Answer (score 5):

You could implement the OnTouchListener.

```
  anImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //Check between +- 10px jsu tto have some are to hit 
                int centerX = (v.getWidth() /2);
                if(event.getX() > centerX - 10) 
                     && event.getX() < centerX + 10)){
                    //Do your magic
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The event contains the coordinates for the event. 
Then you can compare that either to the the boundaries you set up or get the correct pixel from the image an check if it is white.

Comment: that what i want, how to how much it is far from left and right!! and to click only in the middle? and that image is only for explaining purpose and not the real image

Comment: i found a solution already, but i will try yours because i think it is better than setting fixed width @Flaxie

Answer (score 3):

I would advise to put another transparent control in your relative layout on top of ImageView with paddings you need, and subscribe to its onClick event. This way you can be sure only proper area was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

What i did is I used two images One for Show your Image and Secound is show only Some Part of that where you want to click

Please Note My Secound Image is my transparent image. So use one1 as a transparent image. And use its Click Event.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@xml/shape"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/one1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

now create xml and create shape.xml file which is give to Linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="20dip" />

<stroke
    android:width="100dip"
    android:color="#A0ffffff" />
```

Comment: no sir the image is fixed and I cannot put margin to it, it's shape will be different!! i need it like shown in the image in the question

Comment: i vote it up because it is usefull, but I found another solution better than adding other stuff to my current code, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution by myself: thanks all for replying:

```
private View.OnTouchListener imageViewOnClickListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();

        if (173 <= x && x <= 671) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```